# Is it possible to interact with telegram groups voice chats using a JS bot API like node-telegram-bot-api or telegraf.js

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node.js-telegram

I've seen telegram bots being able to join voice chats and play sounds or music, similar to how discord music bots do. Is is possible to do such a thing from within a JS bot API like `node-telegram-bot-api` or `telegraf.js`?
ChatGPT gave me this for telegraf.js:

```
bot.command('joinvoice', (ctx) => {
    const chatId = ctx.message.chat.id;

    const botMember = ctx.message.chat.getMember(ctx.botInfo.id);
  
    const voiceChatId = 'YOUR_VOICE_CHAT_ID';

    ctx.telegram.sendChatAction(chatId, 'join');
    ctx.telegram.sendVoiceChatAction(chatId, voiceChatId);
    ctx.reply(`The bot joined your voice chat.`);

});
```

Firstly, I couldn't seem to get the voice chat id from my group's voice chat, but anyway this wouldn't work since I checked and `sentVoiceChatAction(chatId, voiceChatId)` is not a valid method from withing `ctx.telegram`, so certainly ChatGPT invented that. When I told him the fact that there is no such function in `telegraf.js` or `node-telegram-bot-api`, it seemed to change its mind and told me that, nor `telegraf.js`, nor `node-telegram-bot-api` have the capability to interact with telegram voice chats. Then I search online about bot APIs who can manage voice chats and only found results about voice messages. The conclusion I arrived at is that telegram bots simply can't interact with voice chats like discord bots, but that begs the question how telegram music bots that join voice chats and play music are made?